# Delete an object specific action

Tags: custom-object, delete, object, action

How could I delete an object specific action?

Here is a screenshot in which you can see that there is no such option as Delete, only Edit on the right of the action list item.
[image]

I have a **System Administrator** profile:

[image]

Comment: are you accessing as system administrator? Is this button is part of any managed package?

Comment: @sanketkumar, It is a standard Salesforce functionality.

Comment: As I am logged in system administrator, I have the option to delete a quick action

Comment: @sanketkumar, how could I check with which role was I logged?

Comment: click on your username on the upper right side and select my setting and select personal and then select advanced user detail. check your profile there.

Comment: @sanketkumar, I updated the question.